# UITableView перенос текста

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. при длинно тексте программа должна оатоматически переночить его на строку ниже. Вроде и написанно все верно, и какичесво скорок "0" а оно всераное не делает то, что нужно. Помогите плиз!

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
        int elementNumber = [indexPath section];

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                 reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    SMXMLElement *elem = [[self.globalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* tmpStr = [elem attributeNamed:@"text"];
    NSString* tmpStrT = [elem attributeNamed:@"author"];
    NSArray *children = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tmpStr, tmpStrT, nil];

    cell.textLabel.text = [children objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [children objectAtIndex:1];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
        int elementNumber = [indexPath section];

    SMXMLElement  *elem=[[self.globalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *str = [elem attributeNamed:@"text"];
    UILabel *longi = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 0)];

    longi.numberOfLines = 0;
    longi.text = str;
    [longi sizeToFit];

    float i = longi.frame.size.height;
    [longi release];

    return i;
}
```

Comment: А что собственно должно по вашему переноситься в вашем  коде? Что вижу я:


-вы создаете надпись в функции возвращающей размер ячейки (зачем - непонятно, я уже несколько раз вам писал про соотв. методы NSString), но тут же уничтожаете ее, а если бы и не уничтожали - на экран вы ее все равно не добавили


-вы присваиваете строку textLabel, но у него-то вы не сделали число строк и не дергали sizeToFit, с чего бы ему изменяться


-отдельный идиотизм выдергивать строки из словаря, вставлять их в массив и тут же снова вытаскивать из массива и присваивать их еще- зачем?

Comment: NSString неверно отображает! У него есть глюки и моя, блин программа, попадает под эту беду! 

Я создаю Лайбл с задоным по длинне размером. что б он сделал перенос в нужном мне месте. 
Говорю что линий неограничено
Добовляю текст с лайбл (сейчас он вылезает за рамки)
Потом я делаю соотвецтвие с размерами лайбла. 

Далее, если он не влезает увиличиваю высоту (вот тут по идея должен быть перенос) При этом значение я записываб во флоат
Больше мне не нужен longi я очишаю его

и возврашаю значение флоата!


Вот так я вижу свою прогу !

Comment: Ладно, допустим, но откуда textLabel должен узнать что он должен подстраиваться, а не просто обрезать как ведет себя надпись по умолчанию?

Comment: А всеголишь, мне надо было сделать numberOfLines в методе cell. и вылядит это такЖ

 cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
Вуаля

Comment: я в первом комменте вообще-то это написал:**-вы присваиваете строку textLabel, но у него-то вы не сделали число строк**[равным нулю - недописал]**и не дергали sizeToFit, с чего бы ему изменяться**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Подсчет высоты ячейки](http://www.imaladec.com/lessons/calculatehighetcell/).

Comment: Спасибо за помошь. Тут действительно то, что надо =)